# how to add date to number in hive

Tags: hive

I want to perform addition on date field and int field.

I am executing the below query. It's throwing the error. I am not able to add. In this `create_date` is DATE data type and `duration` is INT data type.

```
SELECT (create_date+duration)
FROM course;
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that `duration` is in days, you can try `date_add` function.

**Function signature**

```
date_add(string create_date, int duration)
```

> Adds a number of days to create_date: date_add('2008-12-31', 1) = '2009-01-01'.

**Usage**

```
select 
  date_add(string create_date, int duration) 
from 
  course;
```

Reference:

- [Date functions in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Comment: For [spark 2.1+](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions), the first parameter `startdate` can be "date/timestamp/string", while `days` can be "tinyint/smallint/int".