# How to select clients who logged during last 30 days, current_date - 30 does not work in Oracle SQL, HiveQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, hive

How can I take all clients who logged during last 30 days from today in Oracle SQL Developer (HiveSQL because it is query to Hadoop)?

I try to use below code but it does not work:

```
select * from my_table
where logged_time >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
```

Comment: Oracle or Hive?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add date to number in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454663/how-to-add-date-to-number-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle:

```
select * from my_table
where logged_time >= sysdate - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

For Hive if logged_time is a timestamp:

```
select * from my_table
where to_date(logged_time) >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,30)
```

Or like this:

```
select * from my_table
where logged_time >= timestamp(concat(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,30),' 00:00:00.0'))
```

If logged_time is a date, then you do not need to_date function or conversion to timestamp:

```
select * from my_table
where logged_time >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,30)
```